# Как установить свой шаблон в Yii2?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Как установить свой шаблон в Yii2? В официальном справочнике ничего по этому поводу не нашел, кроме отрывков, которые не дают полного представления как устанавливать шаблоны.

Comment: Вот тут: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/479214/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%B8-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0  вы спустя 6 часов относительно **ДАННОГО** вопроса задаете вопрос что такое шаблон... значит вы не знаете что это, но спрашиваете как его установить. Отсюда вопрос - что вы подразумеваете под словом `шаблон` и что вы тогда искали по этой теме, если не знаете что это?

Comment: Алексей Шиманский - возможно, если мне удасться его установить, то я сомгу понять что это такое. Я понимаю, но мне трудно пока понять как шаблоны работают в Yii2. Возможно я не до конца понимаю что такое шаблон.

Answer (score 0):

В контроллере пишете `$this->layout = 'admin';`.При этом он должен быть в папке /views/layouts/

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку шаблоны это виды, их можно создавать точно так же, как и обычные виды. По умолчанию шаблоны хранятся в папке *@app/views/layouts*. Шаблоны, которые используются в конкретном модуле, хранятся в подпапке *views/layouts* папки модуля. Вы можете изменить папку шаблонов по умолчанию, используя свойство *yii\base\Module::layoutPath* приложения или модулей.

Когда вы рендерите вид, вызывая метод *render()* из контроллера, к результату рендеринга будет применен шаблон. По умолчанию будет использован шаблон *@app/views/layouts/main.php*.

Вы можете использовать разные шаблоны, конфигурируя yii\base\Application::layout или *yii\base\Controller::layout*. Первый переопределяет шаблон, который используется по умолчанию всеми контроллерами, а второй переопределяет шаблон в отдельном контроллере. Например, код внизу показывает, как можно сделать так, чтобы контроллер использовал шаблон *@app/views/layouts/post.php* при рендеринге вида. Другие контроллеры, если их свойство *layout* не переопределено, все еще будут использовать *@app/views/layouts/main.php* как шаблон.

```
namespace app\controllers;

use yii\web\Controller;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    public $layout = 'post';
    
    // ...
}
```

Для контроллеров, принадлежащих модулю, вы также можете переопределять свойство модуля *layout*, чтобы использовать особый шаблон для этих контроллеров.

Поскольку свойство *layout* может быть сконфигурировано на разных уровнях приложения (контроллеры, модули, само приложение), Yii определяет какой шаблон использовать для контроллера в два этапа.

На первом этапе определяется значение шаблона и контекстный модуль.

- Если *yii\base\Controller::layout* свойство контроллера отлично от
  *null*, используется оно, и модуль контроллера как контекстный модуль.
- Если *layout* равно *null* (не задано), происходит поиск среди родительских модулей контроллера, включая само приложение (которое по
  умолчанию является родительским модулем для контроллеров, не
  принадлежащих модулям) и находится первый модуль, свойство *layout*
  которого не равно *null* . Тогда используется найденное значение *layout*
  этого модуля и сам модуль в качестве контекста. Если такой модуль не
  найден, значит шаблон применен не будет.

На втором этапе определяется сам файл шаблона для рендеринга на основании значения *layout* и контекстного модуля. Значением *layout* может быть:

- Псевдоним пути (например, *@app/views/layouts/main*).
- Абсолютный путь (например */main*): значение *layout* начинается со слеша. Будет искаться шаблон из папки шаблонов приложения, по умолчанию это *@app/views/layouts*.
  Относительный путь (например *main*): Будет искаться шаблон из папки шаблонов контекстного модуля, по умолчанию это *views/layouts* в папке модуля.
  Булево значение false: шаблон не будет применен.

Если у значения layout нет расширения, будет использовано расширение по умолчанию - .php.

Ссылка на офф. документацию Yii2 Framework: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/structure-views