# Что такое шаблон и что такое тема?

Tags: php, yii, yii2, шаблоны

Что такое шаблон и что такое тема? Шаблон не может быть темой? Зачем в Yii2 есть разные шаблоны, разве одного не достаточно?

Comment: Причем тут `yii2` и шаблоны? Общий  шаблон например - это скелет сайта. Это общее понятие для всех сайтов, а не конкретно в `yii`. А скелет для каждого сайта свой естественно.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский все-таки шаблон в Web - это файл, который преобразуется в html-разметку шаблонизатором, а не то что вы написали.

Comment: @PavelMayorov шаблон - это общая разметка с элементами, которые могут быть общими  для нескольких страниц сайта. Разве нет? А общий шаблон применяется для всего сайта. Соответственно это скелет

Comment: @АлексейШиманский то, о чем вы пишите, называется "макет"

Comment: Pavel Mayorov Хм..Значит есть - Макет, шаблон и тема сайта? А что такое "basic" и "advanced" в Yii2? А то я слышал что это не шаблоны, тогда встаёт вопрос о том, что это?

Comment: @PavelMayorov Да. Казалось бы шаблон - часть макета. Но в целом получается макет - одним большим шаблоном)) Кстати, в доках `yii` https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/structure-views.md#Создание-шаблонов-  как я понял у них макет - это шаблон)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да, верно, макет - это тоже шаблон.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Шаблон - это **файл**, который описывает как отображать конкретную страницу сайта, или часть страницы. После обработки шаблонизатором шаблон превращается в html-страницу, которая передается в браузер.

Тема - это **набор файлов**, которые определяют внешний вид всего сайта. Тема может содержать по отдельному шаблону для каждой страницы сайта.

Но не следует думать о шаблоне как о части темы: в `yii` у сайта может вообще не быть тем, но шаблоны страниц быть обязаны.

PS по результатам обсуждения в комментариях:

Есть еще шаблон проекта (не путать с просто шаблоном). Шаблон проекта - это заготовка, с которой можно начать делать сайт. Сам по себе шаблон выбранный проекта не влияет ни на что, кроме того времени, которое придется потратить на создание сайта. И уж точно шаблон проекта никак не влияет на внешний вид сайта.

Comment: Pavel Mayorov- А стоит ли использовать базовый шаблон в Yii или лучше научиться самим их писать? Как обычно делают профессионалы?

Comment: @Niko_D никакого "базового шаблона" в `yii` не существует.

Comment: Pavel Mayorov -как? Есть "basic" и "advanced" - https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/doc/guide/2/tutorial-start-from-scratch/

Comment: @Niko_D это не шаблон, а шаблон проекта. Внезапно, в `yii` это совсем разные вещи...

Comment: Pavel Mayorov -  а yii2-twig - это тоже шаблон проекта?

Comment: @Niko_D нет, `yii2-twig` - это шаблонизатор. Точнее, адаптер шаблонизатора.